# how to Change height of different Divs

Tags: javascript

i need increase height #post1 and decrease height of post2 and post3, when I click #slice1.
when i click #slice2 , post1 must be decrease and post2 must be increase, and when i click slide3, post3 must be increase and post2 must be decrease.

## Slice1,2,3 is another div, which is outside of #post1,2,3 .

```
 $("#slice1").toggle(function(){
     $('#post1').animate({height:650},1000);
 },function(){
     $('#post1').animate({height:230},1000);
 },function(){
     $('#post2, #post3').animate({height:230},1000);
 });
```

Comment: #Slice1 is another div, which out side of #post1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
$("#slice1").click(function(){
     $('#post1').animate({height:650},1000);
      $('#post1').animate({height:230},1000);
      $('#post2, #post3').animate({height:230},1000);
 });
```

UPDATE:

Ok now I think I know what you are looking for.
Take a look at this

http://jsfiddle.net/mV353/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of animating the height directly, you may want to toggle classes:

```
$("#slice1").click(function(){
     $('#post1').toggleClass('open650');
     $('#post2, #post3').toggleClass('open230');
});
```

Where the CSS classes are:

```
.open650 { height: 650px; }
.open230 { height: 230px; }
```